# Selecting dates according to given days in dhtmlx scheduling calender

Tags: php, calendar, scheduling

I have applied dhtmlx calender first time in my php code where i am trying to schedule events in calender only on those days which are selected by the user and in between start date to end date. 
For eg. ( If user selects Monday, Friday from 11-sept-2017 (startdate) to 30-sept-2017 (enddate). Like this image:-[This is the image where user selects days and startdate and end date.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGhOR.png)

Then in calender it will book event only on monday and Friday which are coming in between startdate and enddate.
But in my calender i am getting a whole line from startdate to enddate which i don't want.

[This is my calender image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brq5x.png)

Any help would be appreciated...
Thanx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

It must have to do with recurring events in dhtmlxScheduler  https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/recurring_events.html#serversideintegration .

From your screenshots, it looks like your records have start/end dates of recurring series, but are interpreted as regular events rather than series.

From the original docs, when you create a recurring event its start and end date values have the following meaning:

> start_date - the start date of the first event in a series in the
>   format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' (Date Format Specification).
>
> end_date - the end date of the last event in a series in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00' (Date Format Specification).

and

> rec_type - (varchar) defines the logic of repetition. This field is
>   filled in automatically
>
> event_length - (long int) the actual time length of an event in seconds
>
> event_pid - (int) the parent id of a series of events

So what you see could happen either if you don't save **'rec_type', 'event_length' and 'event_pid'** to the database , or if you don't load these properties to the client - then your records won't be recognized as recurrings.

And the solution is to make sure you save write these properties to the db and return them with the rest of properties when you load data to the client-side.

If it won't work right away - please update your questions with the your server-side code and some info of your database structure and show how the server response for scheduler.load action looks like